# Is there a way to alias scope variable for a html node?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-transclude, transclusion

I Have a directive myDirective which has a template and transcended html (`transclude: true`)
myDirective template has a repeater `ng-repeat="item in transformSourceData"`and transcluded template uses `item` to render page, now my question is how to use `item` in transcluded html without saying `$parent.item`
I want something like `init-my-scope="item=$parent.item"` so that I do not need to use $parent.item in my transcluded html.

The reason to do that is I need my transcluded html to preserve its origin scope since it has bindings to its originated scope and only uses `item` from parent, and also it interpolate some string from a model which is binded to its scope which evaluate to `!item.property`

Here is the structure:

```
myModule.directive('myDirective', function() {
var directive = {
        bindToController: true,
        controller: myDirectiveController,
        controllerAs: 'vm',
        restrict: 'E',
        transclude: true,
        scope: {
            data: '=sourceData',
        },
        template: '<div ng-repeat="item in transformSourceData"ng-transclude></div>'
    };
    return directive;
});
```

and in my template:

```
<my-directive source-data="someData"> 
    <span>{{$parent.item.property}}</span>

    <!--This is what I want to use-->
    <!--<span>{{item.property}}</span>-->

    <span ng-if="{{originScope.someCondition}}>{{originScope.data}}</span>
</my-directive>
```

in above example `originScope.someCondition` will evaluate to `!item.property` but `item.property` wont be available and the value can be retrieved using `$parent.item.property`
so I need to somehow tell my template when ever you encounter `item` refer to  `$parent.item` and all the places which is binded to `$parent.item.xyz` will be rather bind to `item.xyz`.

Comment: I think you misunderstand how transclude works.  Transclude takes the HTML from the parent  **after it has been parsed** and inserts it into the `innerHTML` of the element inside the template. Therefore, the bindings being transcluded are evaluated against the parent scope, and inserting them into an `ng-repeat` wouldn't make sense.

Comment: @Claies: Hi, thanks for your reply, let me brief you what I am gonna achieve from this directive, it might then make sense or might be I am doing something wrong....I am creating a directive which gets an array and transform it into a matrix (array of objects and each object have one property whose value is another array) so this way I am breaking my array and using some condition on my directive template only renders few of this matrix item (some kind of virtual repeater), I want my directive to be reuse and any one can uses their own template (transcluded template) and what my directive...

Comment: and what my directive do is to create limits the rendering of very log lists, so other users will use my directive with their own template as a nested html for `myDirective`, I want users to have access to origin scope for their template nested under `myDirective` however I am interested for $parent.item which is created by `ng-repeat` but instead of using `$parent.item.xyz` I want to use `item.xyz`

Comment: as presented here, your code isn't even a [mcve];  to start with, your template has a `transformSourceData` property that doesn't exist (or that your template doesn't have access to, anyway), you are describing the parent HTML as the template (which it is not), and your use of `$parent` here doesn't make sense at all, since even if the HTML was evaluated against the directive and not the parent, `$parent` would refer to `myDirectiveController` (parent of the `ng-repeat`).  There isn't any way at all this code would work, if I even tried to create an example myself to tinker with.

Comment: also, your title is a bit misleading;  your problem seems to be with how to manage templates, properties, and transclusion, and not about "initializing a variable".

Comment: @Claies: well, agree, I tried to keep it as short as possible, Ill try to update my question, I tired to only mentioned the necessary information for my issue and I chose this title since I though there should be a way in angular to initialize a variable as a scope variable for my html node, something like : `<div ng-some-directive="item=$parent.item"></div>` so that the where ever I use item in my nested html it will refer to $parent.item